# Can't initialize sessionFactory. Hibernate 3 in Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven

this is my ApplicationContext.xml. I can't run my program because of this error:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

I must say that HibernateVoc extends HibernateDaoSupport. I've looked at several web pages in search of how to use HibernateDaoSupport, wether these are the correct properties to initialize sessionFactory... I've not managed how to work out the problem.

Thanks y'all!

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/voc" />
<property name="username" value="root" />
<property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>com/ju/voc/domain/words/Word.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/ju/voc/domain/categroies/Category.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="hibernateVoc" class="com.ju.voc.data.HibernateVoc">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

P.S. I'm using Maven, so I download libraries from there.

Comment: Some class must be missing in your classpath. The "caused by" line in the stack trace should tell you more about where it happens and thus which class might be missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the dependency to hibernate.

Because the `spring-orm` artifact [handles ORM using plain Hibernate, JPA, JDO and iBatis](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html) (and it hardly ever makes sense to use them all), all of these depenencies are [marked as optional](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html), which means that you have to reference the dependencies in your pom.xml. Here's how to reference the latest stable version of hibernate core:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That was all, so easy, despite having Spring in action and other one about Java 6 EE, I wasn't read that I must have included dependencies for Hibernate... I first tried iBATIS and I'm trying Hibernate now and I can't stand up for so many confusion, so many versions and xml files and different ways of configuring the same thing... I know this is very powerful but it's a mess at the beginning. I mean, I don't know wether I'm doing the right things to learn a Java framework... What have you done?

Answer (score 3):

The exception you got (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) means that you forgot to include a library jar in your application. Try to deep analyze the log trace, and find the missing class in order to include the proper jar. Probably you missed hibernate dependency.

Comment: I've set as dependencies in pom.xml: junit, mysql and org.springframweork. which is left?

Comment: Hibernate is missing. To use Hibernate, you need Hibernate.